# Why we can add an element on both sides like this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose $A$ is a set equipped with a binary operation $+$.

How I can prove if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$? Why we can add an element on both sides like this?

Comment: You can prove it by induction.

Comment: a=b iff (a,c)=(b,c) only if +(a,c)=+(b,c)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28mathematics%29#Equality_in_mathematical_logic

Comment: @KennyLau This has nothing to do with induction except when $A = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?  It's a good question.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui I disagree that x=y iff (P(x) iff P(y)) in most practices because usually our class of propositions is artificially limited by the domain of discourse or the order of the logical system. "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absense". I agree if we mean All propositions, and the part needed here is just x=y only if (P(x) iff P(y)) which is a corollary of "x=x" .

Comment: @JacobWakem Yes I agree. I think the point is that any decent axiom system for a theory with equality should have as a trivial consequence that $x = y \implies f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: This is a comment that should probably not be included in any answer, but there are some rare contexts in mathematics where $=$ is not the same as equality of sets, and where the equation like the one in the question might have a less trivial proof. This is the case in combinatorial game theory, and the equation would even become false if the operation were replaced by "ordinal sum", which unfortunately does not preserve the-equivalence-relation-standardly-represented-by $=$ in this way.

Answer (score 7):

A simple explanation is that saying $a=b$ literally says that $a$ and $b$ are the exact same mathematical object. Hence 'adding' $c$ to $a$ on the right is one the same as 'adding' $c$ to $b$ on the right (adding in quotes because what I am *really* referring to is the given binary operation).

Note that the converse, $a+c=b+c \Rightarrow a=b$, is not guaranteed to be valid unless every element of the set $A$ has unique *right* inverses, and in such a case, we say that $c$ has right inverse $c_R^{-1}$ and we can apply that right inverse to both sides to obtain $a+c+c_R^{-1}=b+c+c_R^{-1}\Rightarrow a+e=b+e$ where $e$ is an identity element (required for the notion of a right inverse to make sense) and thus $a+e=b+e\Rightarrow a=b$.

Comment: Actually, $a + c = b + c \implies a = b$ just requires $c$ to be right cancellable, not necessarily invertible.

Answer (score 2):

This also confused me when I first started studying math.  A binary operation $+$ on $A$ is a function $+: A \times A \rightarrow A$.  By $a+b$, we mean $+(a,b)$.

The question is why if $b, c \in A$ with $b =c$, then $+(a,b) = +(a,c)$?

The naive way to do this is to just say: it's obvious; two things are "equal" if they are the same.  If $b$ is the same thing as $c$, then $+(a,b)$ is obviously the same thing as $+(a,c)$, because $b$ is the same thing as $c$.  There is no difference in the expressions.  If I add $3$ to the number $2$, that's obviously the same thing as adding $3$ to the number $1+1$, because $1+1$ is the same thing as $2$.

Another way if you want to think more carefully about it: fix $a \in A$.  Then the mapping $x \mapsto +(a,x)$ is a function $f: A \rightarrow A$.

So this reduces the problem to showing the following: if $f$ is a function from $A$ to $A$, and $b, c \in A$ with $b = c$, then $f(b) = f(c)$.  Can you see why this is tre?

Comment: I like the idea of explaining $+$ as a function $+:X\times X \rightarrow X$. I think, however, you can omit the part where you fix $a$, provided that you have suitable rules for determining the equality of ordered pairs. So +1 to this answer for introducing $+$ as a function at the very beginning, +1 to goblin's answer for applying the binary function directly.

Answer (score 1):

For the binary operation to be *well-defined*, it must be the case that for any elements $a, b, c, d$ with $a=b$ and $c=d$, $a+c = b+d$. It is not at all clear in your question what further conditions there are on the binary operation $+$, but being well-defined is absolutely necessary for what you've written to make sense.

The converse is not necessarily true, however. Since you have not mentioned the existence of inverses for your binary operation, there is no reason to assume that $a+c=b+c \implies a=b$. Taking an example from ring theory, replacing your '+' with multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, we have $2 \times 3 = 4 \times 3 = 0$, but $2 \neq 4$.

See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100642) for a more concise explanation of what I've said.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is what equality means.

From a very formal perspective, equality is just some relation between mathematical objects. It becomes interesting if we restrict it's behavior via some axioms, like this:

$$x=y \Rightarrow \left[\phi(x) \leftrightarrow \phi(y)\right]$$

for any one-argument proposition $\phi$.

That is, we require equal elements to behave exactly the same. If something is true for $x$, it is true for $y$, and vice versa.

You particular case corresponds to $\phi(x)=x+c$ for a fixed $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $a=b$ now add c to a:  $$a+c$$ Now:$$a+c = a+c$$ but $a=b$, so we can replace $a$ in the second member, then $=> a+c = b+c$

To prove that $a = a$, $0+a = a$ and $a+0 = a$ then, $a+0 = 0+a => a=a$.